# 'this' for structs?

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, this

A short, maybe stupid question.
For classes and structs, sometimes I like to have member variables with the same name as constructor arguments. For example:

```
class Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;

    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to do this for structs too, but you can't use 'this' in struct constructors (their use is reserved for classes, I think). Is there a way to do this or should I just give my arguments another name?

Comment: `this` is as valid for `struct` as for `class`. There's actually very little difference between the two. But remember `this` is a pointer.

Comment: What FredLarson said, but with the addition that the only difference is that struct members are by default public, and class members default private.

Comment: @AlexWilson: Yeah, that's what I meant by "very little" difference, as opposed to no difference. 8v)

Comment: This example looks more like java than c++

Comment: For what it's worth, it's probably best not to do this.  I can't count the number of bugs I've had to fix where someone forgot a `this->` or thought they were using a variable that was hidden by another variable.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis It's just for a small struct. Actually, the example I gave is what I needed it for, so there's very little room for error's there. For bigger classes or structs, I tend to use different names for the arguments and the member variables. Thanks for your advice though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it, but its a *pointer* just as in classes:

```
this->x = x;
```

By the way, a `struct` and a `class` are exactly the same thing for everything but the default *access specifiers*.

Comment: Hmm, I'm used to C#, where you use this.members. I suspected I was missing something very basic. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: For the record, normally I figure things like this out myself, but this is for an assignment that I haven't got much time for, so I figured it was faster to ask.

Answer (score 6):

What you really should be doing is using the constructor's initializer list:

```
class Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;

  public:
     Vector3(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

};
```

but concerning your misgivings about using `this` in a struct, there is no difference w.r.t a class.

I would like to add that it really is worth having some kind of naming convention for data members, to avoid confusion. Favourites tend to be a trailing underscore or a leading `m_`.